# PostgreSQL SQL query to find number of occurrences of substring in string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I’m trying to wrap my head around a problem but I’m hitting a blank. I know SQL quite well, but I’m not sure how to approach this.

My problem:

Given a string and a table of possible substrings, I need to find the number of occurrences.

The search table consists of a single colum:

**searchtable**

```
| pattern TEXT PRIMARY KEY|
|-------------------------|
| my                      |
| quick                   |
| Earth                   |
```

Given the string "Earth is my home planet and where my friends live", the expected outcome is 3 (2x "my" and 1x "Earth").

In my function, I have variable bodytext which is the string to examine.

I know I can do IN (SELECT pattern FROM searchtable) to get the list of substrings, and I could possibly use a LIKE ANY clause to get matches, but how can I count occurrences of the substrings in the table within the search string?

Comment: Please include the actual code for the function.

Comment: "how can I count occurrences of the substrings in the table within the search string?" Don't count. Calculate it. Pseudo code: `(length(originl string) - length(replace(original string, substring, '')) / length(substring)`

Comment: @ZoharPeled I ended up solving the problem myself shortly after posting the question, but I used exactly this method. I'll post the complete solution for reference.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will update it in case someone else comes across the question. The table is really only one column as described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easily done without a custom function:

```
select count(*)
from (values ('Earth is my home planet and where my friends live')) v(str) cross join lateral
     regexp_split_to_table(v.str, ' ') word join
     patterns p
     on word = p.pattern
```

Just break the original string into "words".  Then match on the words.

Another method uses regular expression matching:

```
select (select count(*) from regexp_matches(v.str, p.rpattern, 'g'))
from (values ('Earth is my home planet and where my friends live')) v(str) cross join
     (select string_agg(pattern, '|') as rpattern
      from patterns
     ) p;
```

This stuffs all the patterns into a regular expression.  Not that this version does not take word breaks into account.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=63b14d59f92fd03135b77b444f7a3a30) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_matches(body TEXT, OUT matches INTEGER) AS $$
DECLARE
    results INTEGER := 0;
    matchlist RECORD;
BEGIN
FOR matchlist IN (SELECT pattern FROM searchtable)
LOOP
    results := results + (SELECT LENGTH(body) - 
        LENGTH(REPLACE(body, matchlist.pattern, ''))) / 
        LENGTH(matchlist.pattern);
END LOOP;
matches := results;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```